# VSCode: "No debug adapter, can not send 'evaluate'"

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, lua

I am trying to run lua 5.4 code in VSCODE but I am getting this error:`No debug adapter, can not send 'evaluate'`. My debugger is "Local Lua Debugger" and the launch.json is

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lua-local",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "program": {
                "lua": "lua54",
                "file": "bot.lua"
            
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And the lua file itself is

```lua
print("Y/N?")
local input = io.input()
if input  == "no" then
    print("yes")
end
```

The error shows up every time I want to input something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.input()` is for you to **read external files**, in it you pass the path of a file you want to read.

If you want to write something and store it in the variable, try using `io.read()`